# Android change image in a ImageView?

Tags: android

I have a picture as a resource, that I need to modify thanks to OpenCV, then I would like to put my new Image in the original ImageView.

I tried this way, but :

```
public class VerifianceActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */   
    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            if (status == LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS ) {
                // now we can call opencv code !

                Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cmc7);
                Mat myMat = new Mat();
                Utils.bitmapToMat(mBitmap, myMat);

                Imgproc.cvtColor(myMat, myMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
                Utils.matToBitmap(myMat, mBitmap);

                ImageView mIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                mIV.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);//NPE
                //this line is suppose to work, but the app crashes.
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

            } else {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {;
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_5,this, mLoaderCallback);
        // you may be tempted, to do something here, but it's *async*, and may take some time,
        // so any opencv call here will lead to unresolved native errors.
    }
}
```

Any advice ?
I got a NullPointerException as an error

Comment: Please mark the line with NPE.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you need to call

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

BEFORE accessing any `Views` or they will be `null` such as

```
 ImageView mIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Since the `Views` exist inside the `layout` which you inflate with `setContentView()`, they don't exist until you inflate that `layout` so they will return `null` if you try to initialize them before inflating the `Layout`

Answer (score 3):

you have to call `findViewById` after `setContentView` not before, otherwise the view hierarchy does not exist, and `findViewById` returns null

```
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  ImageView mIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  mIV.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
  //this line is suppose to work, but the app crashes.
```

Comment: Just a bit faster than me, as always ;)

Comment: Thanks, I though it was a line taht was supposed to display the view, so I wanted to change it before :/ Now it works ^^

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to do

```
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

before

```
            ImageView mIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mIV.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to call

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

in onCreate(), at least, *before* trying to call findViewById(..)

i bet, your imageview is null, because it could not find the resource.

```
ImageView mIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```